# Can we Sort Crystal Report Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using a javaScript Function to preview report but now i want to Sort Crystal report is this possible ?
i am using following function for showing report

```
<script language="javascript">
function print_Click()
{           
window.open("rptviewer.aspx?rptname=RollNumber","atif","status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,scrollbars=1");
}
 </script>
```

and this is my button code

```
  <asp:button id="btnprv" runat="server" text="رپورٹ دہکھیں" width="90px" backcolor="SteelBlue" forecolor="White" OnClientClick="print_Click();"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports is not something that happens on the client side, so...

No, you cannot sort it using javascript.

What you need to do is pass a parameter to `rptviewer.aspx` and then do the sort through Crystal Reports on the server before the result is sent to the browser.

I haven't touched CR for many years (thankfully), so I cannot give advise as to how you would sort it (but my guess would be it's easier to sort the data source, rather than get CR to do it).